# Canvas is getting jerk and behaves improperly when Image Panning/Dragging limit is added

Tags: android, math, android-custom-view

I have made the custom ImageView which can zoom and pan. The problem is with the panning/dragging bound I have tried to cap the bound by giving limit to the left top edge if it goes below Zero or negative. When I am doing this it works till one of the condition is occured like X becomes 0 or Y becomes 0 if both becomes 0 it gets jerk and some weird behaviour happens even if the less than zero condition is there it goes out of bound ..

code is with the comments easy to understand please help

here is the code

```
package com.example.customView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/* @description : Custom View Zoom
 *
 */

public class ZoomView extends ImageView {

    // Maximum and Minimum Zoom
    private static float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
    private static float MAX_ZOOM = 3.0f;

    //Different Operation to be used
    private final int NONE_OPERATION=0;
    private final int DRAG_OPERATION=1;
    private final int ZOOM_OPERATION=2;
    private float mWidth= 1047;
    private float mHeight=800;
    private boolean dragged=true;

    // Mode to select the operation
    private int mode;

    //Track X and Y coordinate of the finger when it first touches the screen
    private float mInitialX = 0f;
    private float mInitialY = 0f;

    //Track the amount to translate(Drag) the canvas along the X and the Y coordinate
    private float mTranslateX = 0f;
    private float mTranslateY = 0f;

    //Track the last translated X and the Y coordinate while panning so that canvas does not get the jerk (Issue was happening when we change the position again and again )
    private float mPreviousTranslateX = 0f;
    private float mPreviousTranslateY = 0f;

    //ScalingFactor i.e. Amount of Zoom
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;
    float gx=0,gy=0;
    private Rect rect ;
    private Matrix matrix;


    private ScaleGestureDetector mDetector;


    // Called if used from code
    public ZoomView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        // Intialize ScaleGestureDetector
        mDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ZoomListener());
        rect= new Rect();
        Matrix matrix= new Matrix();
    }

    //Called if used from XML
    public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ZoomListener());
        rect= new Rect();
        Matrix matrix= new Matrix();
    }


    //handle the touch event of the view with the detector to get the scalingFactor and also keep the track of
    // the touch events like drag and zoom event using booleans
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // Handles all type of motion-events possible
        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Event occurs when the first finger is pressed on the Screen

            // setting the mode to Drag Operation
            mode = DRAG_OPERATION;

            // Store the initial X and Y of the first finger when touches on the Screen. Take the difference with the previous translation so as to avoid the jerk in canvas.
            //Initial difference will be X and Y since previousTranslation will be ZERO.
            mInitialX = event.getX() - mPreviousTranslateX;
            mInitialY = event.getY() - mPreviousTranslateY;

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Event occurs when the finger move across the screen and also when the finger is kept pressed on the screen

            // Update the translate value constantly as the event is occured at every move
            mTranslateX = event.getX() - mInitialX;                // Translate value is calculated by diff from current and initial
            mTranslateY = event.getY() - mInitialY; 

        /*    float [] matrixValues = new float[9];
            matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
            if (mode == DRAG_OPERATION) {

                if(rect.left<0 || matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X]<0)
                    mTranslateX = mPreviousTranslateX;
                else
                mTranslateX = event.getX() - mInitialX;                // Translate value is calculated by diff from current and initial
                if(rect.top<0 || matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]<0 )
                    mTranslateY=mPreviousTranslateY;
                else
                mTranslateY = event.getY() - mInitialY;


                        }*/


        //    Log.d("Print", " TranslateX::" + mTranslateX + " Translate Y::" + mTranslateY);

            // If finger is kept pressed it will still consider the move so to avoid that use this value
            //Initial X and Initial Y can not be used directly because they were adjusted  using the previous translation values. So need to add those
            // values to InitialX and InitialY so that the actual coordinates of the finger are retrieved.
            // Using distance Forumla
            double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.getX() - (mInitialX + mPreviousTranslateX), 2) + Math.pow(event.getY() - (mInitialY + mPreviousTranslateY), 2));
                if(distance > 0) {
            dragged = true;

            }



            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            //Event occurs when the second finger is pressed down


            // If second finger is pressed on the screen with the first set the Mode to Zoom operation
            mode=ZOOM_OPERATION;

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //Event occurs when all the finger are taken of the screen

            //If all the fingers are taken up there will be no operation
            mode = NONE_OPERATION;
            dragged= false;
            // All the operations are done.Store the previousTranslate value here. ( Might not need at the time of second finger down ??)
            mPreviousTranslateX = mTranslateX;
            mPreviousTranslateY = mTranslateY;

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            // Event occurs when the second finger is taken of the screen while first finger is pressed


            // Second finger is taken up stop zooming and again Drag Operation
            mode=DRAG_OPERATION;
            break;
        }

        // give the event to the mDetector to get the scaling Factor
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        //We need to invalidate the canvas to redraw itself for the changes.Here we need to invalidate only when zoom is done and drag operation has happened
        //or else for the Zoom which was happening in the onScale function
        if((mode==DRAG_OPERATION && mScaleFactor!=1f && dragged ) || mode==ZOOM_OPERATION)
        {

            invalidate();
        }



        // we are handling the touch event
        return true;
    }




    //Everything that is going to reflect on the screen will happen in on draw
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    //Save the canvas to set the scaling factor returned from detector
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,gx,gy);
        Log.d("Print", "mScaleFactor::" + (mScaleFactor));                 //- 1) * mWidth );
        Log.d("Print", " mTranslateX::" + mTranslateX + " mTranslateY::" +  mTranslateY);
        Log.d("Print", " ::" + mTranslateX/mScaleFactor + " mTranslateY::" +  mTranslateY/mScaleFactor);


        float[] matrixValues = new float[9] ;

    //Check the bound that we never pan past the top of left edge of the
/*    if((mTranslateX) < 0) {
        mTranslateX=0;

    }
    ////Check the right bound.
    // eg : Height of display is 1280. When it is zoom by 2 it is 1280 . when it is zoom by 3 it is  2560
    // Compare translateX times -1 to (scaleFactor - 1) * displayWidth.
    //If translateX is greater than that value, then it has gone over the bound. So we set the value of translateX to (1 - scaleFactor) times the display width.
    // Notice that the terms are interchanged... it's the same as doing -1 * (scaleFactor - 1) * displayWidth
    else if((mTranslateX) > (mScaleFactor - 1) * mWidth){
        mTranslateX=(mScaleFactor - 1 )* mWidth;
        Log.d("Print", " InDraw mTranslateX::" + mTranslateX);
    }

    if((mTranslateY)< 0)
        mTranslateY=0;
    else if((mTranslateY) > (mScaleFactor - 1) * mHeight)
        mTranslateY= (mScaleFactor-1)* mHeight;*/


        if(rect.left<0 || matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X]<0)
            mTranslateX = mPreviousTranslateX;
        else
        mTranslateX = mTranslateX;                // Translate value is calculated by diff from current and initial
        if(rect.top<0 || matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]<0 )
            mTranslateY=mPreviousTranslateY;
        else
        mTranslateY = mPreviousTranslateY;

    //divide by the scale factor here,
    //otherwise it will end up with excessive panning based on our zoom level since the translation amount also gets scaled according to how much we've zoomed into the canvas.
      canvas.translate(mTranslateX / mScaleFactor, mTranslateY / mScaleFactor);   

    // Draw anything more if needed here ....

      // Restore the canvas to balance the save Canvas which removes all the last modification before save.


      super.onDraw(canvas);

      canvas.getClipBounds(rect);
       Log.d("Print", " Canvas X::" + rect.left + " CanvasY::" + rect.top );


      matrix = canvas.getMatrix();


      Matrix m = new Matrix();
       m = canvas.getMatrix();
       float[] arr = new float[9] ;
        m.getValues(arr );
       Log.d("Print", " CanvasMatrixX::" + arr[Matrix.MTRANS_X] + " CanvasMatrixY::" + arr[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] );

        canvas.restore();
    }






/* @name : ZoomListener
 * @description : Class which defines the listener for ScaleGestureDetector while extending abstract
 *
 */
    private class ZoomListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

/*
 * ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 *
 * @description: Method gives the scaleFactor from the detector
 *
 * ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 */
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // getting the scaleFactor from the detector
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();                // gives the scaling factor from the previous scaling to the current
            Log.d("Print", "detector scaling Factor" + mScaleFactor);


            gx = detector.getFocusX();
            gy = detector.getFocusY();

            // Limit the scale factor in the MIN and MAX bound
            mScaleFactor= Math.max(Math.min(mScaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM),MIN_ZOOM);
            Log.d("Print", "Bounded scaling Factor" + mScaleFactor);

            /*//Force canvas to redraw itself only if the one event is to happen (say Zooming only ) else do not invalidate here for multi operations
               As what we de for scrolling or panning will not reflect here. So we will add this in onDraw method
            invalidate();*/

            // we have handle the onScale
            return true;
        }

        @Override
            public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

                super.onScaleEnd(detector);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give the screenshots of this weird behavior?

Comment: @a.ch.  what is happening is When it get scaled and i try to pan it down from top left ..as my bg images gets drag down ..while coming to the (0,0) i.e. topleft  till then its fine but as soon as it goes in negative it goes in the conditon of rect.top and rect.left here it plays with x nd y i mean jerks ...jerks means sometimes it goes in x axis sometimes in y ...like that way ...hope u got it ..how to show the screenshots of dancing image ..?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you are invalidating the view unnecessarily(even after limit). You should be checking the bounds in `onTouch` itself and make the decision of whether to redraw your view or not. You should stop redrawing once the limit is reached.

Check the value of `mTranslateX` in `onTouch`  method and call invalidate.

```
...
if (mTranslateX >= 0 || mTranslateY >= 0) {
    invalidate();
}

if (mTranslateX < 0)
    mTranslateX = 0;
if (mTranslateY < 0)
    mTranslateY = 0;
...
```

Comment: I did try that by keeping the if(rect.left>=0 || rect.top >=0) { isTranslate= true ; and there is a condition where I am doing invalidate() if its true then only it will invalidate or else not but still it did not work with the keeping it in the bound

Comment: unnecessary invalidation seems to be the only problem here. You need to check your if condition once again.. add mtranslateX, mtranslateY to it..